# How to replace the headerview of listview with flip animation

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in which I am adding a headerview with
`listview.addHeaderView(view);` 
method now i want to replace this headerview with new view by applying a flip animation only on header not on the whole listview can anyone provide me a good solution of this problem?? or suggest me library that provide me the required functionality

Comment: So, you want to know how to apply flip animation on HeaderView of a ListView?

Comment: Yes @HamidShatu only on headerview

Comment: could you please post your code what you have tried?